# Structuring a large complex module in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I am creating a complex module in TypeScript (parsing PE file structure, similar to what Mono.Cecil does, but in TS/JS and less sophisticated).

The question is how best to put that functionality in file/folder/module dimensions.

I started with structure similar to C#, with each class in its own file, namespaces (modules) corresponding to large sets of more or less independent functionality and living in subfolders.

Now in TypeScript there are several issues with that. Or maybe the issues are with my being stupid?

1. Every class in a separate file is good for development, but makes no sense for the compiled output. Nobody wants to carry around 24 files instead of one.
2. If I compile everything into one file (tsc -out), contents of each separate file is emitted almost independently, even if they all belong to the same module. TypeScript builds that module up using some funky hacky-looking syntax, not at all what I would write by hand (which would be sticking them all in one module-defining immediately-invoked function).
3. I want my stuff to work in Node.js and browsers. For Node I need to pepper it all with 'export module', but for browser the typical usage is just produce whatever.js and let pages have it in  -- which means I should strip 'export module' back off.

What's the best way to deal with that?

Comment: This is a very broad question. Generally speaking you would use bundling for web, which is outside of TypeScript. If you want it to be runnable on both web and nodejs, you could use the module flag to compile commonjs for node and amd for web. There is a feature request outstanding to allow the same TypeScript code to work with all platforms, but until then using amd with requiresjs allows you to re-use the same TypeScript code on the web as on nodejs.

Comment: That's only if I wanted it to do AMD on web. But most of real-world libraries (you know, jQuery, Knockout...) don't do that AMD ceremony, they just provide you a script and you refer to it from HTML.

I don't mind recompiling with a different option, but changing 18 places in 14 files to add/remove 'export' is not workable.

Comment: The way I do it at the moment is to put my stuff into non-exported module. That means on the web it adds that module to the global scope and scripts can use it. And on Node I add an extra code that manually uses 'exports' variable to satisfy Node's pattern.

Comment: The feature request that is outstanding may help. It will let you write bundle-style code and have the module wrappers removed for nodejs. What do you currently use to combine and minimum for web?

Comment: To combine I use 'tsc -out', which shoves all the output in a single file.

Answer (score 3):

I am currently using require.js and amd modules to structure code. Each class is in a single file, and all that is needed is a require.js bootstrapper. I dont work with node, so cant comment here, but it may be worth having a look.    http://blorkfish.wordpress.com/2012/10/23/typescript-organizing-your-code-with-amd-modules-and-require-js/

Comment: Thanks, great description, very detailed. At the same time it very much highlights the complexity of AMD comparing to just sticking the <script> on the page.

Comment: Work on a large (> 100,000 LOC) web app and let me know how that works out for ya Steve.

Answer (score 0):

The Typescript 1.0+ answer to this is to use modules using the CommonJs syntax

Pass the `tsc` flag

```
--module commonjs
```

to generate CommonJS style modules and in the Typescript files, import the resources using the require syntax

```
import A = require('./A')  //no .ts in the name
```

To use in the browser, use [browserify](http://browserify.org/), most likely associated with [grunt-browserify](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-browserify)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want browserify (See BGR's answer) you can create 2 build processes, one for CommonJS (Node), and another for RequireJS (browsers). The 2 builds could output their results into other folders (e.g. `projectRoot/dist/server`). Hell of a Grunt/Gulp project, but not impossible.

For nice usability I'd also create a **wrapper file** that has no classes/interfaces within, it only includes the other files and chooses what to export. I've just got some hints how to do that:
[TypeScript export imported interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30712638/typescript-export-imported-interface)