# TypeScript export imported interface

Tags: typescript

I use AMD modules and I want to hide a complex interface behind one file that loads several other files and chooses what to expose and how. It works, I use this solution but it feels kinda ugly, mostly with the interfaces.

```
import Types = require('./message-types');
import MessageBaseImport = require('./message-base');
export interface IMessage extends Types.IMessage {} // This is an interface
export var MessageBase = MessageBaseImport; // This is a class
```

Usage:

```
import Message = require('message');
import { * } as Message from 'message'; // Or with ES6 style
var mb = new Message.MessageBase(); // Using the class
var msg: Message.IMessage = null; // Using the interface
```

Any better solutions out there? I don't want to put everything into a single file but I want to `import` a single file.

Answer (score 306, accepted):

There is an export import syntax for legacy modules, and a standard export format for modern ES6 modules:

```
// export the default export of a legacy (`export =`) module
export import MessageBase = require('./message-base');

// export the default export of a modern (`export default`) module
export { default as MessageBase } from './message-base';

// when '--isolatedModules' flag is provided it requires using 'export type'.
export type { default as MessageBase } from './message-base';

// export an interface from a legacy module
import Types = require('./message-types');
export type IMessage = Types.IMessage;

// export an interface from a modern module
export { IMessage } from './message-types';
```

Comment: However, it's illegal to use this style of re-exporting in a namespace

Comment: Is there a one-liner for export and import of an interface in TS similar to your legacy example?  Or is it just a case of importing and then reusing the same line, but changing it to an export eg. `import { IMessage } from './message-types';` and then on the next line have `export { IMessage } from './message-types';`

Comment: Why is that @e-cloud ? Can you give some examples/background?

Comment: @mtpultz Yes it seems your usage is correct and is the only way to do that.

Comment: is this a typescript syntax ?  I haven't seen it before and this was unfortunately difficult to google

Answer (score 85):

Some more examples besides #c-snover's answer from [here](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/f7b8a400c61e168eccb3a888a347f5e0acbe3817/docs/es6-modules-overview.md). You can put them together.

```
import 'jquery';                        // import a module without any import bindings
import $ from 'jquery';                 // import the default export of a module
import { $ } from 'jquery';             // import a named export of a module
import { $ as jQuery } from 'jquery';   // import a named export to a different name
import * as crypto from 'crypto';       // import an entire module instance object

export var x = 42;                      // export a named variable
export function foo() {};               // export a named function

export default 42;                      // export the default export
export default function foo() {};       // export the default export as a function

export { encrypt };                     // export an existing variable
export { decrypt as dec };              // export a variable as a new name
export { encrypt as en } from 'crypto'; // export an export from another module
export * from 'crypto';                 // export all exports from another module
                                        // (except the default export)
```

Comment: Thanks. But why is the last import variant detached from all the others? Shouldn't it be just below the other four?

Comment: It's from the referred site.

Comment: broken link https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/es6-modules-overview.md#all-supported-syntax

Comment: You can find the broken link in the repository's history: https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/f7b8a400c61e168eccb3a888a347f5e0acbe3817/docs/es6-modules-overview.md

Answer (score 5):

In my case particularly, I had to 'declare' the interface instead of exporting it.

```
declare interface IFluxStoreSyncOptions{
  namespacedKey: string;
}
```

In order to use the interface as a type in another file like so:

```
export function FluxStoreSync(options: IFluxStoreSyncOptions){
}
```

This way you don't have to export and import the interface.