# Shorthand to export all definitions from a module in Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typescript2.0

I was wondering if there is a shorthand for exporting all definitions in a module. No way to do that is suggested in the docs. I am looking for something like `export*` for exporting all definitions in the module.

```
/* this is one way according to docs*/
//module1 
const foo = () => {console.log('function foo')}
const bar = () => {console.log('function bar')}
export {foo, bar} 

// module2
import * as m1 from './module1'
m1.foo() 
m1.bar()

/* this is another way according to docs*/
// module1
export const foo = () => {console.log('function foo')}
export const bar = () => {console.log('function bar')}

// module2
import * as m1 from './module1'
m1.foo() 
m1.bar()

/* looking for something like this */
// module1
const foo = () => {console.log('function foo')}
const bar = () => {console.log('function bar')}
export * // looking for something like this

// module2
import * as m1 from './module1'
m1.foo() //doesn't work 
m1.bar() // doesn't work
```

Comment: This is not supported by ECMAScript

Comment: Typescript,

 there is no way to export all properties in single expression `*`

Answer (score 0):

See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/30714301/977206

```
// export the default export of a legacy (`export =`) module
export import MessageBase = require('./message-base');

// export the default export of a modern (`export default`) module
export { default as MessageBase } from './message-base';
```

Also this should work, maybe only for certain types of modules? not sure

```
export * from 'foo';
```